IP Warming and Bounce/Blacklist Management Strategy
I am planning for IP warming and preparing response strategies for potential issues that may arise during the process.
I have a few questions regarding bounce handling and IP blacklist management:

When a bounce occurs, does it make sense to pause sending for a few days and then resume with a reduced volume as a valid response?
If a block bounce happens, is it correct to check the blacklist status and then submit a removal request through sites like the ones listed below to resolve the issue?
(https://www.barracudacentral.org/rbl/removal-request)
When submitting a removal request, will the IP or domain be removed from the blacklist, and if so, how long does it typically take for removal to be completed?

Thank you in advance for your response.
